SQLite contraint: Check sum before INSERT
Let's say I got a table with 2 columns - date and a type.
Type is an Integer between 1 and 5.
Before inserting a new row, I want to check if the sum of type (including the new value) for a given date is less than 7. If not, abort the insert.
I found this, but you can't store procedures in sqlite:
Add contraint that checks sum
I tried this in hope that if CHECK() fails, it will abort!
CREATE TRIGGER check_sum_of_types BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
BEGIN
CHECK((SELECT sum(type) FROM bookings WHERE booking_date = new.booking_date) + new.type) < 7)
END


SQLite was never designed to be a complete and fully-featured database solution.  It supports a limited subset for lightweight needs.  If you need robust checking and triggers, use a real database, like Postgres or MySQL.
